# address of ivar as an argument

Tags: iphone, c, pointers

I am trying to call function but I get error:

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'drawPlot' from incompatible pointer type

```
//call
    drawPlot(&listData);


//header
    void drawPlot(NSMutableArray*);
```

listData is of course NSMutableArray

Comment: are you sure it's not a `NSMutableArray*`?

Comment: of course my fault, it should be listData without ampersand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the &. Your variable is already a pointer. I assume you've declared it like so: `NSMutableArray *listData;`.

So using & is passing a "pointer to a pointer" to a function that is expecting simply a pointer to an NSMutableArray.

Now, there are a number of places in the SDK that expect `NSError **`. And this is when you would use &, e.g:

```
NSError *error = nil;
...
[SomeClass doSomethingReturningError:&error];
if (error != nil) {
    //something bad happened
}
```

So, the difference here is that passing, in your case, `listData` passes the object by value. The variable's value itself cannot be modified (but the contents of the array can be). The other case (`&error`) is passing by reference, which means that the the value of the variable, i.e. the pointer itself, can be modified. That is why you can compare the result, in that case, to nil to see if something went wrong.

A simpler example is to compare the difference between the following:

```
void changeIntByValue(int i)
{
    i++;
}

void changeIntByReference(int &i)
{
    i++;
}

int x=2;
changeIntByValue(x);
NSLog(@"%d", x); // prints 2
changeIntByReference(&x);
NSLog(@"%d", x); // prints 3
```

Passing by value does not allow arguments to be modified, while passing by reference does.

Answer (score -1):

Definition of listData should look something like:

```
NSMutableAarray listData;  //OR 
NSMutableAarray listData[];
```

If the former, then change the drawPlot call to

```
drawPlot(&listData[0])  // OR
drawPlot(listData)
```

If the latter, then change the drawPlot call to

```
drawPlot(&listData [ the index of the listData array member you want to plot]);  // does it work now?
```